# drawable resource not found in lollipop

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, drawable, android-resources

I am using material designing by appcompat v7 for tabview just like play store tabview.

I am using tabbg drawable for Tabs background image.

My apps is running fine. but problem occurs from lollipop. In lollipop device it crashes with the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/tabbg.p
```

BTW my tabbg image is in `res/drawable-xxhdpi/` but In lollipop it is finding the image in drawable-xxhdpi-v4.

How can i solve this problem? Here is my Custom style for metarial design. Please let me know how can i solve it?

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!--   app branding color for the app bar -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@drawable/tabbg</item>
    <!--   darker variant for the status bar and contextual app bars -->
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#222222</item>
    <!--   theme UI controls like checkboxes and text fields -->
    <item name="colorAccent">#FFFF00</item>
    <item name="logo">@drawable/ic_launcher</item>
    <item name="displayOptions">useLogo|showHome</item>
</style>
```